# Import file into microsoft access: field mapping

Tags: excel, csv, ms-access, import

This is driving me insane.  I've been banging my head against importing some excel data into microsoft access.  Silly me for thinking that this should be easy since they are both microsoft products.

There are three excel files of about 40MB each. Four tabs in each file, each tab has the same fields in the same order between the files.  ie, tab A in file 1 has the same field names in the same order as tab A in file 2 and file 3. And the corresponding table in the access database as the exact same field names in the exact same order as in the files also.  Same goes for the other tabs.   There are about 90K rows and about 40 columns in each tab.

The first tab I imported directly into Access and created a new table. Even though the other files have the same layout, I just can't seem to get access to import the other files correctly.  Even though the fields have the exact same names in the exact same order, it keeps screwing up the mapping.

Not grossly, I either get a type conversion error for a field or two (which I also don't get since all the fields in the access table are of type "short text" so i can just import whatever is in the data files with no processing) or a couple of the wrong source fields from the files get imported into the wrong target fields in the database.

It's almost more annoying that just a few fields get messed up because it means I have to check the whole table to figure out if things went off.  And it's not consistent, it screws up differently each time I try it.

I tried importing the data from the excel files and also by saving each tab as a csv.  Nothing works.  WTF am I doing wrong. Happy to try using some other database (filemaker, etc).  I don't care about using access, I just thought it would be easier but I don't get why this is so freaking difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Import data from all worksheets in all files in a folder.

```
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean, blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnReadOnly As Boolean
Dim intWorkbookCounter As Integer
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
Dim colWorksheets As Collection
Dim strPath As String, strFile As String
Dim strPassword As String

' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\MyFolder\ with the actual path to the folder that holds the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\MyFolder\"

' Replace passwordtext with the real password;
' if there is no password, replace it with vbNullString constant
' (e.g., strPassword = vbNullString)
strPassword = "passwordtext"

blnReadOnly = True ' open EXCEL file in read-only mode

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

intWorkbookCounter = 0

Do While strFile <> ""

      intWorkbookCounter = intWorkbookCounter + 1

      Set colWorksheets = New Collection

      Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile, , _
            blnReadOnly, , strPassword)

      For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            colWorksheets.Add objWorkbook.Worksheets(lngCount).Name
      Next lngCount

      ' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
      objWorkbook.Close False
      Set objWorkbook = Nothing

      ' Import the data from each worksheet into a separate table
      For lngCount = colWorksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                  "tbl" & colWorksheets(lngCount) & intWorkbookCounter, _
                  strPath & strFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                  colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
      Next lngCount

      ' Delete the collection
      Set colWorksheets = Nothing

      ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
      ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
      ' Kill strPath & strFile

      strFile = Dir()

Loop

If blnEXCEL = True Then objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWkshtsFilesSepTbls